# Umbraco users cant see some nodes regardless of permissions

Tags: c#, tree, umbraco

I've got a site structure similar to the following:

```
Content
  - Home
    - Articles
      - A1
      - A2
      - A3
    - Categories
      - C1
      - C2
      - C3
```

There are a few more folders but this should illustrate the issue fine. I have a signup process that creates users and allows them access to the back office. However, recently, I've noticed that when a user logs in, some nodes just don't appear for them.

For example, I have a test user that I created and gave access to everything, yet on logging in, they may only see one article in the Articles folder and no categories in the Categories folder. This seems to happen for any user I create, and its always the same nodes that do/don't show.

If the user creates, say, an Article then this wont show in the tree until it has been published. Even saving wont cause it to display in the tree. So saving, and navigating away will cause the node to be "lost".

None of these issues happen for the admin account.

I've tried re-publishing the entire site, reloading nodes on the folders in question, as well as touching the web-config and setting the newly created users to administrators, and still no luck.

**Update**

After a bit of investigation, it seems that the nodes that load initially all have child nodes. As an example if A1 had 2 children, "Link 1" and "Link 2", by my understanding, that will show, A2 and A3 will not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue!

When experimenting with custom trees, I implemented an example for an event that would remove the "Delete" action from the nodes. For some reason this was only rendering the node if it had  children and was owned by the current user (if they weren't admin).

Doh!